# NSPredicate with IN for NSDate

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nspredicate

I wanted to fetch the objects from entity whose `startDate` or `endDate` is greater than the dates 
provided in an array.

I am currently using IN for predicate as follows,

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K IN %@ OR %K in %@", kEntityEventAttributeStartDate, inArray, kEntityEventAttributeEndDate, inArray];
request setPredicate:predicate];
```

But I think it checks for equal dates Where as I want dates which are greater.

Any Idea how to achieve this with `NSPredicate`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "startDate greater than dates in array"? Should it be greater than all values in the array?

Comment: Why do you have an array of dates to check against if the `startDate` and `endDate` have to be greater than all of them? Can't you just take the biggest date and compare with it using `%K > %@`?

Comment: Not all the values but should be greater than at-least one value

Comment: Even in that case you just need to check if the given date is larger than the smallest date in the array.

Comment: I did the way both (Rakesh and PartiallyFinite)of you suggested I am getting the Objects now.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating a predicate which has a start date and end date, I query the model to get all the dates which are between the provided range.

Thanks for the help and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can first sort the date array like:

```
NSArray *dateArraySorted = [inArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Date" ascending:YES]]];

//Select the smallest date - if the date is greater than this then there is no point in checking against others and vice-versa.
NSDate *smallestDate = dateArraySorted[0];
```

From here, I guess you know how to create the predicate.